# Is the System.Addin (MAF) source code somewhere available?

Tags: maf, system.addin

I'm currently evaluating the different ways to create a C# plug-in architecture (mainly MEF vs MAF). System.Addin (MAF) seems interesting but there is no so much informations on the web about it.

I'll be very interesting to see its source code in order to better understand the way System.Addin works.

I googled without success, do you know if Microsoft has published MAF source code somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available on Microsoft's [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.AddIn/System/Addin/Hosting/Store/AddIn.cs,de4c6dc050ca2e23) website.